# How to force Netbeans to display the argument names in the JavaDoc window

Tags: netbeans, arguments, javadoc

When using Netbeans and let the JavaDoc window popup, it doesn't show the argument names, but either `arg0`, `arg1`, et cetera, or the first letter of the variable type (for example `int i`, `boolean b`, `float f`, et cetera). The image below shows that behaviour.

[image: argument names could not be found]

As can be seen the `Color` class, from package `java.awt`,

```
public Color(ColorSpace cspace, float[] components, float alpha)
```

is shown as

```
public Color(ColorSpace cs, float[] floats, float f)
```

How can I solve this problem?

(Notice that I also want to store the API documentation locally, to decrease waiting time. Can I achieve this too with the above problem solved?)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you just need to add the sources jar or zip to your netbeans.
If you're using Mac Os they will probably are going to be at:

Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_32-b05-420.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar

Just copy src.jar to other folder using Terminal and in Netbeans go to

Tools > Java Platforms > Sources > Add JAR/Folder...

Add your src.jar file and restart netbeans.

Comment: I'm not using a Mac OS, so where can I download it?